# Flutter error: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am working on diary flutter android application with firebase real time database.
I am trying to make three functions: add, delete, edit.
For now, add and delete functions work well but edit part causes problems.
When I edit the texts and click 'save', it is updated to firebase itself but it shows "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast" this error. Edit function can be done by clicking value from firebase animated list.
I put lots of effort to fix it and found what is problem with String but couldn't solve it.
Could anyone help me to solve this? Thank you a lot.
Below are models.

```
 //1. Main
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Color(0xfff5f5f5),foregroundColor:Color(0xff0d47a1)),
        splashColor: Color(0xff00bcd4),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xffe9f1f2),
        hoverColor: Color(0xff26c6da),
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'Itim',
      ),
      home: MainPage()));
}
 //2. Main Page
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  late PageController _myPage;
  int selectedPage = 0;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myPage = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    selectedPage = 0;
  }

  List<IconData> iconlist = [
    Icons.home_outlined,
    Icons.add,
    Icons.settings,
    Icons.person,
  ];
  List<Widget> _currentpage = [
    ListOfNotes(),
    AddNotes(),
    SettingsPage(),
    AccountPage(),
  ];
  int _bottomnavindex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'NOTES',
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Graduate', color: Color(0xff0d47a1)),
        ),
      ),
      body: _currentpage[_bottomnavindex],
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.sunny),
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff039be5),
      ),

      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniEndDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
        leftCornerRadius: 30,
        //rightCornerRadius: 0,
        gapLocation: GapLocation.end,
        activeColor: Color(0xffe91e63),
        inactiveColor: Color(0xff0d47a1),
        icons: iconlist,
        activeIndex: _bottomnavindex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          _bottomnavindex = index;
          selectedPage = index;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 //3. AddNotes
class AddNotes extends StatefulWidget {

  AddNotes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddNotes> createState() => _AddNotesState();
}

class _AddNotesState extends State<AddNotes> {
  late PageController _myPage;
  bool _validate=false;
  TextEditingController _controller1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();
   final messageDao = MessageDao();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffe1e9f0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                    minLines:1,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: (_validate)?'CANT BE NULL':null,
                      hintText: 'NOTE TITLE',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Graduate', color: Color(0xffc3dbf0)),),
                    controller: _controller1,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Itim', color: Color(0xff191176)),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                    minLines:1,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'NOTE CONTENT',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Graduate', color: Color(0xffc3dbf0)),),
                    controller: _controller2,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Itim', color: Color(0xff191176)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.small(onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _controller1.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
      if(!_validate){
        add();
      }
    });
        },
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffeab9d6),
          hoverColor: Colors.white,
          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Graduate',color: Color(0xffcd087c)),),),
      ),
    );
  }

  void add(){
    final message = NotesOfApp(_controller1.text,_controller2.text, DateTime.now(), DateTime.now(),DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch);
      messageDao.saveNotes(message);
    _controller1.clear();
    _controller2.clear();
  }
}
 //4. AddNotesToList
class MessageDao {
  final DatabaseReference _notesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  void saveNotes(NotesOfApp notes) {
    _notesRef.push().set(notes.toJson());
  }
  Query getNotesQuery() {
    return _notesRef;
  }
}
 //5. Notes
class NotesOfApp {
  final String NoteTitle;
  final String NoteContent;
  final DateTime created;
  final DateTime editted;
  final int date;
  NotesOfApp(this.NoteTitle, this.NoteContent,this.created,this.editted,this.date);
  NotesOfApp.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)
      : created = DateTime.parse(json['created']),
        editted = DateTime.parse(json['editted']),
        NoteTitle = json['NoteTitle'] as String,
        NoteContent = json['NoteContent'] as String,
                date=json['date'] ;

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{
  'created' : created.toIso8601String().split('T').first,
  'editted' : editted.toIso8601String().split('T').first,
 'NoteTitle': NoteTitle,
  'NoteContent' :NoteContent,
    'date':DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch,
  };
}
 //6. List of notes
class ListOfNotes extends StatelessWidget {
  final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().orderByChild('date');
  List<String> keys=[];
  List<Color> colors = [
    Color(0xffefdada),
    Color(0xffefe6e9),
    Color(0xfff9f0fa),
    Color(0xfff1eef5),
    Color(0xfff8fae2),
    Color(0xfffffcf2),
    Color(0xfffff3ef)
  ];
  ListOfNotes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          Map notes = snapshot.value as Map;
          for(DataSnapshot i in snapshot.children ) {
            keys.add(i.key.toString());
            break;
          }
          return _buildList(context, notes: (notes));
        },
        query: reference,
      ),
    )));
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, {required Map notes}) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 8),
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
            color: colors[Random().nextInt(colors.length)],
          ),
          child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                  title: Text(notes['NoteTitle'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Graduate',
                          fontSize: 10,
                          color: Color(0xff191176),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  subtitle: Text(notes['editted'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff191176),
                          fontFamily: 'Graduate',
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  tileColor: colors[Random().nextInt(colors.length)],
                  onLongPress: () {
                    showAnimatedDialog(
                        animationType: DialogTransitionType.slideFromTop,
                        curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        context: (context),
                        builder: (builder) => Warning(
                              NoteTitle: notes['NoteTitle'],
                            ));
                  },
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => NoteContents(
                              NoteTitle: notes['NoteTitle'],
                              NoteContent: notes['NoteContent'],
                          list:keys,
                            )));
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
              ]),
        ));
  }
}
 //7. Note Content
class NoteContents extends StatelessWidget {
  final String NoteContent;
  final String NoteTitle;
  final List<String> list;
  NoteContents({Key? key, required this.NoteContent, required this.NoteTitle, required this.list}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffe1e9f0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
            ),
            child:Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  onTap:(){Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UpdateNotes(NoteTitle: NoteTitle, NoteContent:NoteContent,list: list,)));},
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18),
                    child: Column(
                    children:[
                      Text('$NoteTitle',style:TextStyle(color: Color(0xff191176),fontFamily: 'Graduate',fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text('$NoteContent',style:TextStyle(color: Color(0xff191176),fontSize:12),),
                    ]),
                  ),
                  onLongPress: (){Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>UpdateNotes(NoteTitle: NoteTitle, NoteContent:NoteContent,list: list,)));},
                )
              ],
            ),)),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.small(
          onPressed: () {
            // print(NoteTitle);
            // print(NoteContent);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffeab9d6),
          hoverColor: Colors.white,
          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          child: Text('BACK',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Graduate',
                  color: Color(0xffcd087c),
                  fontSize: 8)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 //8. Update
class UpdateNotes extends StatelessWidget {
  final String NoteTitle, NoteContent;
  final List<String> list;
  UpdateNotes({Key? key, required this.NoteTitle, required this.NoteContent,required this.list})
      : super(key: key);
  final controller1 = TextEditingController(),
      controller2 = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller1.text = '$NoteTitle';
    controller2.text = '$NoteContent';
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffe9f1f2),
          shadowColor: Color(0xffe9f1f2),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffe1e9f0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff191176)),
                    controller: controller1,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 12,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLines: 500,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff191176)),
                    controller: controller2,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.small(
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xffeab9d6),
            hoverColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              showAnimatedDialog(
                  animationType: DialogTransitionType.fade,
                  curve: Curves.easeInOutCubicEmphasized,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  context: (context),
                  builder: (builder) => Warning2(
                        NoteTitle: controller1.text,
                        NoteContent: controller2.text,
                    list: list,
                      ));
            },
          child: Text('SAVE',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Graduate',
                  color: Color(0xffcd087c),
                  fontSize: 8)),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
 //9. Update pop up
class Warning2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> list;
  Warning2({Key? key, required this.NoteTitle, required this.NoteContent, required this.list}) : super(key: key);
  final String NoteTitle,NoteContent;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClassicGeneralDialogWidget(
      titleText: 'SURE WANT TO UPDATE ?',
      onPositiveClick:(){
      Update('$NoteTitle','$NoteContent',list);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } ,
        onNegativeClick: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
    );
  }
}
Future<void> Update(String NoteTitle,String NoteContent,List<String> list) async {
  String key="";
  String result="";
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().get();
  for(DataSnapshot i in snapshot.children ){
      key = i.key.toString();
      for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        if(key==list[i]){
          result=list[i];
        }
      }
    }
  await ref.child(result).update({
    "NoteTitle":"$NoteTitle",
    "NoteContent":"$NoteContent",
    "editted":DateTime.now().toIso8601String().split('T').first,
  });
}
//10. delete pop up
void check(String NoteTitle) async{
  print(NoteTitle);
  final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  String key="";
  final snapshot = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().get();
  for(DataSnapshot i in snapshot.children ){
    if(i.child('NoteTitle').value.toString()==NoteTitle) {
      key = i.key.toString();
      break;
    }
  }
  reference.child(key).remove();
}
class Warning extends StatelessWidget {
  Warning({Key? key, this.NoteTitle}) : super(key: key);
  final String? NoteTitle;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClassicGeneralDialogWidget(
        titleText: 'SURE WANT TO DELETE ?',
        onPositiveClick:(){
          check('$NoteTitle');
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        } ,
        onNegativeClick: (){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
    );
  }
}
```

These are codes and in' Notes' model, there is "Map<dynamic, dynamic>".
These dependencies are from `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.20
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  flutter_animated_dialog: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
     - family: Graduate
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Graduate-Regular.ttf
     - family: Itim
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Itim-Regular.ttf
```

And this is how error shows on application. Other things on page are showed well and other pages work well too. But only this content part is missing.
[image: error on app]

And this is the full error code.

```
 ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
    The following _CastError was thrown building:
    type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ListOfNotes.build.<anonymous closure> (package:diaryreal/ListOfNotes.dart:32:46)
#1      FirebaseAnimatedListState._buildItem (package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart:209:30)
#2      SliverAnimatedListState._itemBuilder (package:flutter/src/widgets/animated_list.dart:624:30)
#3      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:471:22)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1236:28)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1169:67)
#6      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:325:35)
#7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1213:24)
#8      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1146:7)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#11     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#13     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#17     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#19     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:237:11)
#20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
```

And this is what I got 'debug' tab.
[image: debug tab]

Comment: To facilitate debugging, could you add the stackTrace that is displayed in your console? At least the first 50 lines if possible.

Comment: @Chance
Hello, thank you for your reply.
It has been not long since I started coding and could you tell me where to find stackTrace?
Is it about the error message or is it similar to the 'import' part of dependencies in main.dart?

Comment: StackTrace is the error trace, the widgets are prepared to display the entire error trace from its origin. When your widget fails for some reason the console will receive an error log while your screen turns red in debug mode.

Comment: @Chance Thank you for letting me know. I am not 100% sure that I uploaded what you want but I uploaded error message and also the debugging error part. Could you check it and let me know if you need more another information? Thank you so much

Comment: Well, the error is that you're saying that `snapshot.value` is a `Map`, but it's a String. Inside that string would you have a json?
The `as` operator asserts (converts) that the type x is indeed x, and should only be used if you are sure the converted type is indeed the expected one, if you are not sure the expected value is x but y, so it's better to use the `is` operator to reassert the type.  [type-test-operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators)